# Trying to visualize the wording of a question about finding the resistor that carries the highest voltage

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, parallel, series

I know how to find the higgest current in the resistor, it's just the visual that I'm second guessing.

This is the question.

[image: question]

This is the what I drew from it

[image: visual]

Comment: You've drawn: a series combination of a 330 ohm resistor and a 470 ohm resistor connected in parallel with a parallel combination of four 1k ohm resistors.

Comment: So you think I did it right?

Comment: Try comparing what I wrote to the problem statement and decide for yourself.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong then

Comment: nvm, I'm right...

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and it has not been long that I've learned it. so this can get a little puzzling sometimes.

Comment: A second grader with a box of crayons could do a better job of drawing a schematic.  Yuk, what a mess.  And no, there is no excuse.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You do know this was done in paint right? Also it's a rough sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the parallel combination ... in series with the parallel combination

You have two "combinations" in *series*, they will look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f207Ib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each combination is described as a *parallel* combination of some resistors, the first will look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB2MaW.png)</sup>

The second combination is similar but with four elements in parallel.

You can substitute the second diagram for "combo 1" in the first diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing is wrong. Think of it like this. Block A = 470 parallel with 330. Block B = Four 1K parallel resistors. Now Block A and Block B are in series.